# First order logic. Describing that there exists a set with exactly 2 elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

∃∃(∈ ∧ ∈ ∧ ¬(=))

Is this a valid way to describe that? I believe it's correct but I'm not so sure

Comment: No: what you've written means that the set $A$ contains at least two elements.

Answer (score 3):

$\exists A \exists x \exists y ~(x \in A \land y \in A \land \lnot (x=y) \land \forall z (z \in A \Rightarrow (z=x \lor z=y)))$.

Comment: Isn't this second order logic?

Comment: @NathanKaufmann No.  Second-order logic allows quantifiers of collections of elements.  First-order logic limits the scope of quantifiers to elements.  So, for example, you can't express the well ordering principle over $\Bbb N$ in first-order logic because it requires you to talk about all subsets of $\Bbb N$.  That's why there are first-order "non-standard" models of $\operatorname{Th} (\Bbb N, +, \cdot)$ that are not well-ordered.